# Nested Bootstrap 3 Accordion not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm struggling getting the second level accordion to expand. Any ideas?

The first level expands, but the inner level does not. I think I might have too much markup! But I cannot find a very good example.

See http://jsfiddle.net/pzh20/fcjq2dd0/

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" style="width:80%; margin:0 auto;">
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
    <div class='panel-heading'>
        <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#week52014'><span class='fyw'>5</span><span class='ztdate'>2014-2015</span><span class='total'>£weektotal</span></a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id='week52014' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
        <div class='panel-body'>
            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                <div class='panel-heading'>
                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#week52014' href='holacg52014'><span class='bu'>New Market</span><span class='ztdate'>31/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£buweektotal</span></a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id='holacg52014' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                    <div class='panel-body'>
                        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>
                                <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#holacg52014' href='#holacg3152014'><span class='bu'>New Market</span><span class='ztdate'>31/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id='holacg3152014' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                                <div class='panel-body'>
                                    <p><span class='depart'>Food Retail</span><span class='total'>£143.01</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>
                                <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#holacg52014' href='#holacg3052014'><span class='bu'>New Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id='holacg3052014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                <div class='panel-body'>
                                    <p><span class='depart'>Paella</span><span class='total'>£436.25</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>
                                <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#holacg52014' href='#holacg2952014'><span class='bu'>New Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id='holacg2952014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                <div class='panel-body'>
                                    <p><span class='depart'>Food Retail</span><span class='total'>£36.60</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>
                                <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#holacg52014' href='#holacg2852014'><span class='bu'>New Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id='holacg2852014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                <div class='panel-body'>
                                    <p><span class='depart'>Paella</span><span class='total'>£330.42</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                <div class='panel-heading'>
                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#week52014' href='lmdqbm52014'><span class='bu'>Old Market</span><span class='ztdate'>31/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£buweektotal</span></a></h4>
                </div>
                <div id='lmdqbm52014' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                    <div class='panel-body'>
                        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>
                                <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#lmdqbm52014' href='#lmdqbm3152014'><span class='bu'>Old Market</span><span class='ztdate'>31/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id='lmdqbm3152014' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                                <div class='panel-body'>
                                    <p><span class='depart'>Food Retail</span><span class='total'>£143.01</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>
                                <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#lmdqbm52014' href='#lmdqbm3052014'><span class='bu'>Old Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id='lmdqbm3052014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                <div class='panel-body'>
                                    <p><span class='depart'>Paella</span><span class='total'>£436.25</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>
                                <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#lmdqbm52014' href='#lmdqbm2952014'><span class='bu'>Old Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id='lmdqbm2952014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                <div class='panel-body'>
                                    <p><span class='depart'>Food Retail</span><span class='total'>£36.60</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                            <div class='panel-heading'>
                                <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#lmdqbm52014' href='#lmdqbm2852014'><span class='bu'>Old Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id='lmdqbm2852014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                <div class='panel-body'>
                                    <p><span class='depart'>Paella</span><span class='total'>£330.42</span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
            <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#week42014'><span class='fyw'>4</span><span class='ztdate'>2014-2015</span><span class='total'>£weektotal</span></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id='week42014' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
            <div class='panel-body'>
                <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                        <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#week42014' href='holacg42014'><span class='bu'>New Market</span><span class='ztdate'>31/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£buweektotal</span></a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id='holacg42014' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                        <div class='panel-body'>
                            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                                <div class='panel-heading'>
                                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#holacg42014' href='#holacg3142014'><span class='bu'>New Market</span><span class='ztdate'>31/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id='holacg3142014' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                                    <div class='panel-body'>
                                        <p><span class='depart'>Food Retail</span><span class='total'>£143.01</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                                <div class='panel-heading'>
                                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#holacg42014' href='#holacg3042014'><span class='bu'>New Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id='holacg3042014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                    <div class='panel-body'>
                                        <p><span class='depart'>Paella</span><span class='total'>£436.25</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                                <div class='panel-heading'>
                                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#holacg42014' href='#holacg2942014'><span class='bu'>New Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id='holacg2942014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                    <div class='panel-body'>
                                        <p><span class='depart'>Food Retail</span><span class='total'>£36.60</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                                <div class='panel-heading'>
                                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#holacg42014' href='#holacg2842014'><span class='bu'>New Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id='holacg2842014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                    <div class='panel-body'>
                                        <p><span class='depart'>Paella</span><span class='total'>£330.42</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                        <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#week42014' href='lmdqbm42014'><span class='bu'>Old Market</span><span class='ztdate'>31/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£buweektotal</span></a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id='lmdqbm42014' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                        <div class='panel-body'>
                            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                                <div class='panel-heading'>
                                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#lmdqbm42014' href='#lmdqbm3142014'><span class='bu'>Old Market</span><span class='ztdate'>31/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id='lmdqbm3142014' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                                    <div class='panel-body'>
                                        <p><span class='depart'>Food Retail</span><span class='total'>£143.01</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                                <div class='panel-heading'>
                                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#lmdqbm42014' href='#lmdqbm3042014'><span class='bu'>Old Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id='lmdqbm3042014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                    <div class='panel-body'>
                                        <p><span class='depart'>Paella</span><span class='total'>£436.25</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                                <div class='panel-heading'>
                                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#lmdqbm42014' href='#lmdqbm2942014'><span class='bu'>Old Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id='lmdqbm2942014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                    <div class='panel-body'>
                                        <p><span class='depart'>Food Retail</span><span class='total'>£36.60</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                                <div class='panel-heading'>
                                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#lmdqbm42014' href='#lmdqbm2842014'><span class='bu'>Old Market</span><span class='ztdate'>30/08/2014</span><span class='total'>£budaytotal</span></a></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id='lmdqbm2842014' class='panel-collapse collapse '>
                                    <div class='panel-body'>
                                        <p><span class='depart'>Paella</span><span class='total'>£330.42</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Regards
Pete

Answer (score 0):

Heres the answer for nested accordion.Hope it works.
A working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wk6LLnew/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="head1">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  Tab1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">

                 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="innerhead1">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  Tab1
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="innercollapseOne" class="panel-collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="innerhead2">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                Tab2
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="innercollapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="innerhead3">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                 Tab3
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="innercollapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="head2">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                Tab2
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="head3">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                 Tab3
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $("#head1").click(function()
         {
            $("#collapseOne").toggle();
         });

        $("#innerhead1").click(function()
         {
            $("#innercollapseOne").toggle();
         });

        $("#innerhead2").click(function()
         {
            $("#innercollapseTwo").toggle();
         });


       $("#innerhead3").click(function()
         {
            $("#innercollapseThree").toggle();
         });     


         $("#head2").click(function()
         {
            $("#collapseTwo").toggle();
         });

         $("#head3").click(function()
         {
            $("#collapseThree").toggle();
         });
```

Comment: Thanks for this.

You have several DIVs with the same ID, it obviously works, but is that the reason?

Also, in the example I posted, I was using the layout in the Bootstrap examples. They use the HREF value whereas you don't. 

Regards
Pete